# How to edit a file with ed?

Tags: linux, text-editors

I have to deal with `ed` in order to edit a configuration file. The [manpage](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ed+1.i386+NetBSD-7.0.2) is written in the usual painful style which doesn't make give me hope that I'll understand how to use `ed` after spending an hour or two to read it, e.g.

- says `q     Quits ed.` without any further statements which doesn't help because there're a million things to consider when quitting a buffer-based editor and a manpage author has to link them there
- provides 0.5 examples and
- explains line addressing and replacement before basic commands.

What simple key combinations can I use to edit a file which is too complicated for `echo` and redirection?

`vi`, `nano` and `pico` are not available in the NetBSD 7.0.2 installation shell which I have to use.

Comment: It's a line based editor and such you will have to know where you want stuff to go, if it's something different than replacing. You really should talk to the people responsible if there isn't another editor like `vi` available. Without further specifying what you want to do to the file, there isn't any meaning full help. As you would usually specify something like "insert text on line 5" or "remove line 12". [This](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ued.htm) has some more examples on how to use it, but it is going to be painful.

Comment: If you have to use `ed` then read [Actually using ed](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/actually-using-ed/) and [The GNU ed line editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html).

Comment: In practice, avoid using `ed` if you are not familiar with it. Try to find another editor. Perhaps you have some `nano`. Or save the file on some USB key, edit it with another computer or operating system.

Comment: To expand on @BasileStarynkevitch 's comment:  Try running `apropos editor` or `man -k editor`. You may find alternative text-based editors which may be easier to use such as `nano` or `pico`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually quite like `ed`, mostly because you can make minor edits without it grabbing the whole screen, so you can easily see your command history. However, I'd hate to be stuck with it.

Some tips:

- Run `cat -n FILE` before you use ed. You're gonna need to know the line numbers.
- See the line you think you want to edit with `<linenum>p` (or just `<linenum>`). This also moves the cursor.
- Most commands are vi-like:

  - `i <text>` inserts the text before the current line (whichever was the last mentioned line, `n` will tell you if you're not sure).
  - `c` changes the current line to whatever you write afterwards, until you EOF with `CTRL-d` or type a line with a single `.`.
  - `d` deletes
  - `/<text>` searches
  - `w` writes to disk
  - etc etc. See the man-page or DavidPostill's link for more commands.
- Make backups with `cp`. Regularly.